# Streamlit st.Text_input OnChange and st.Button OnClick for same Input not working correctly

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to use a user text input with the ability for the user to hit the enter key or use the button to write the text below the button and then clear the input text after the button is clicked or enter is used. When I try this code it will clear the text input and write the text correctly but when I use the enter key but when I use the button it will write the value but clear it right away and seems to clear the st.session_state.my_text after the button value is written.

```
import streamlit as st

if "my_text" not in st.session_state:
   st.session_state.my_text = ""

def submit():
    st.session_state.my_text = st.session_state.widget    
    st.session_state.widget = ""

st.text_input("Enter text here", key="widget", on_change=submit)

st.button("Submit", on_click=submit)

my_text = st.session_state.my_text

st.write(my_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The weird behavior when using button is caused by the `on_change` in

```
st.text_input("Enter text here", key="widget", on_change=submit)
```

**Example scenario**

- User enters "aa" for example
- Presses the button
- Executes submit, (**notice this, there was a change in the value from empty to "aa"), and sets st.session_state.widget to empty
- Executes the rest of the code below
- It comes back to submit again because the **on_change was triggered.
- Now the value of st.session_state.my_text is empty

This is the reason why there is no string printed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this code, you might find out how it works

```py
import streamlit as st
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
logger = st.logger.get_logger(__name__)

logger.info('initial')
if "my_text" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.my_text = ""

def submit():
    logger.info('submit %s', st.session_state.widget)
    st.session_state.my_text = st.session_state.widget
    st.session_state.widget = ""

st.text_input("Enter text here", key="widget", on_change=submit)

st.button("Submit", on_click=submit)

my_text = st.session_state.my_text

st.write(my_text)
logger.info('--terminate')
```

A log like the following appears

- first at 11:46:10
- "text only" at 11:46:29
- "text and button" (6 lines) at 11:46:49

```py
2024-02-25 11:46:10.359 initial
2024-02-25 11:46:10.479 --terminate
2024-02-25 11:46:29.061 submit text only
2024-02-25 11:46:29.062 initial
2024-02-25 11:46:29.065 --terminate
2024-02-25 11:46:49.201 submit text and button
2024-02-25 11:46:49.201 initial
2024-02-25 11:46:49.205 --terminate
2024-02-25 11:46:49.327 submit
2024-02-25 11:46:49.328 initial
2024-02-25 11:46:49.330 --terminate
```